# I want to build a DC powered computer, what are the gotchas, where are the parts?

Tags: dc, ac, dc-dc-converter, ups

Google builds its servers with a Battery in the box so that they don't need a UPS.  I'm wanting to do the same, but I'm wondering what all the gotchas might be for doing this, and where I'll find the components to put it all together.

I'm wanting to figure out how to eliminate the DC -> AC -> DC conversion (and all its losses) and just run the system off a DC power supply with a battery in place of the current ATX power supply.

I'm thinking a standard ATX power supply to give me the 12 volts for normal operation, then a kick over onto a gel cell battery when the power goes off, eliminating the UPS.  I'm looking for ideas on how to do this economically using off the shelf parts and whatever amount of soldering needed to make it work.

Comment: maybe a little light weight depending on your needs http://www.mini-box.com/DC-DC

Comment: @kenny - They have options up to 250W: http://www.mini-box.com/M4-ATX?sc=8&category=981.  That said, this feels a lot like a consumer electronics question to me. Perhaps it's a better fit for Superuser?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way would be to replace the ATX PSU with a 12V DC (Automotive) PSU.  Then you can run the system off a 12V DC power supply / charger, and a standard car (or leisure) battery.

Comment: It is important that when using an automobile as the power source that the power supply includes appropriate noise filtering and voltage limiting, such that voltage surges or spikes from the back-EMF caused by the alternator (up to ~400V if I recall correctly) are not passed to the computer itself.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any real gotchas on the computer end - but you will end up with a computer powered by 12 (or 24 or whatever) volts DC, which you will have to provide via an outside power supply. Which becomes another failure point.

I'd only bother with this if you have a real reason to do so - like you've already got battery-backed DC infrastructure in your site or something.

If you just want a computer that's got battery in the box, buy a laptop.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of issues.

1. You can't take off ATX power supply and put 12V DC PSU instead. It's because PC utilizes a lot of different voltages. Such as 3.3V, 5V. Look at [ATX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) standard. Of course, you can add to 12V DC PSU another, smaller size DC-to-DC convertors to 3.3, 5 and other voltages you will need.
2. The charging voltage of battery is above 12V. Usually it is in range from 13 to 15V. You need to check datasheet for battery. So you can't use ATX power supply to charge it. Or you need to rework it to add needed voltages. Think about how you will charge battery. The another good idea may be take laptop parts (as they can work from 12V supply) and build on their base your custom PC. Con is high price for details.
3. Maybe it is good idea not to use ATX PC, but take some monoblock PC ("thin client"). They often have their own power supply. Often they gives 12-19V output, because it is good value. And on motherboard this voltage is converted by internal converters to voltages needed by ICs.
4. > If you just want a computer that's got battery in the box, buy a laptop

   It is good idea. But better is to buy ATX PSU with integrated battery. They are used in industrial systems and costs big money. But they worth it if you really need such thung.

The really good advice: please, write your situation and what you want as comprehensive as you can.

Comment: I'd also note that while ATX specifies a lot of voltages, some of them are absolutely not needed on any recent boards, e.g. -5 and -12. IIRC they were added because of ISA or some similar long dead stuff.

Comment: Yes, you are right. -5V and -12V are needed for ISA and COM ports. They are now obsolete. But other power lines (3.3V, 5V) are used in modern systems. :-(

Comment: I think I've seen some mini- (or maybe micro-, or flex-, etc.) ATX boards which did not need any power lines except 5V. I'm not sure, through, how one can find such ones on the market.

Comment: Yes. There are such. But it is very difficult to find them. And one need to very carefully read specifications.

Comment: What if you remove the battery complication, say its handled elsewhere? Just want to adapt a PC to run on some kind of standard DC voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Since the computer will spend most of its time powered from the mains, it makes sense to optimize efficiency for this scenario in order to save money on electricity costs.

Powering a PC from 12V (not an ATX supply) only makes sense if the cost savings on the UPS outweigh the extra electric bill caused by inefficiencies introduced by double conversion (mains to 12V, then 12V to lower voltages).

However, in a modern PC, most of the power is drawn from the 12V rail, so it might not be as bad.

Besides a laptop, there are other simple solutions:

- [PicoPSU](http://www.mini-box.com/s.nl/it.A/id.417/.f).

This is a small switching converter which generates voltages needed by a PC from a 12V source. It is intended to power small, low-power mothermoards, like Micro-ITX and the like. Just supply some 12V, and you're done. It is expensive, though.

- Intel NUC and similar micro-PCs

Many of these small PCs run from an external wall wart DC adapter. Some will run on 12VDC. Also, they draw very little power, so this will extend your battery life.

However, you also need a screen that will run from 12VDC...

Comment: "However, you also need a screen that will run from 12VDC..." Not hard to find if you're flexible about your resolution requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I,my trying the same thing. The first step is figuring out what the voltages are that come out of the ac/dc power supply and building a dc/dc power supply to match those voltages. You will need to test the wires, I think there are 3. If you put diodes right after the ac/dc power supply then you can hook the original wires back and connect to the Molex connector. You will need to know the amp draw from each of the 3 voltages that come from the ac/dc power supply as well. As in, how many amps and volts is each of these wires going to draw, so I can use parts that are able to handle that many amps. Then build 3 different power supplies on the same board so you will have your voltages. I say 3 because that's how many voltages a Molex connector has. Just make sure the current does not go into the power supply from the Molex connector. It might be cheaper to buy a dc/dc power supply.

Answer (score -2):

If you can get enough batteries to have some 100-120V, you can try to feed this 100V DC right into your ATX power supply. Most of them should work just fine without any modifications.

Comment: You would be right if they just had dumb full wave bridges at the front followed by a switcher driving a transformer.  However, modern supplies will have a PFC front end.  DC might or might not confuse it.  It is dependent on the exact PFC implementation.